# Package References in F#

Tags: reference, f#, nuget, nuget-package

I am wondering if there is a way to bundle group of certain packages to load in to a new project outside of the PM(package manager). Like a predefined script?

thanks

Comment: @Foole corrected the abbreviation

Comment: like [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/)?

Comment: @Carsten that will work. now on to reading more in depth about it

Comment: check out my fsharp-quickstart project - it's a set of shellscripts that document all the command line invocations you need to set up various f# projects. https://github.com/martindemello/fsharp-quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly managed by Paket.  It can add nuget package references to projects (like NuGet), but also has the option of [generating include scripts](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-generate-include-scripts.html) for use in .fsx files.

For details, see the [Paket FAQ](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/faq.html).